# How can I talk directly to a WebSockets server without using a programming language like Python?

Tags: websocket

I would like to connect to a server using WebSockets but do not want to pull in a complex environment like Python just to repeatedly send small pieces of data over the wire (this is not a fast computer and Python sometimes takes a noticeable moment or two for itself to initialize each time).

That said, WebSockets is a sufficiently complex protocol - it incorporates transparent ping/pong, framing and other (admittedly pretty awesome) features - that it would take quite a while to implement enough of the protocol to make a usable client from scratch.

I'm looking for something which opens the socket, handles the underlying protocol and lets me handle just the data I need to send, kind of like "websocket netcat".

(Context: I need to talk to Chrome's WebSocket-based remote debugging server from the commandline.)

**EDIT**: So far I've found [this proof-of-concept example written in C which uses libcurl](https://blog.maxux.net/?post/2013/08/13/%5BPoC%5D-WebSocket-single-small-request-with-libcurl); protocol-wise, it would have to be the simplest way to get started with cURL handling the HTTP keepalives and so forth (cURL doesn't speak WebSockets itself yet), but for some reason Chrome is not responding to this program's instructions at all. I've managed to get it to send identical headers to the Chrome remote debugger via WireShark, but it's still sending differently formatted data.

Chrome's debugger's request header starts with `81 ac 99 2f fa 22 e2 0d 97 ....`, whereas the C program sends `81 1f 7b 22 69 64 22 3a 31 ....`. The `81` is identical, at least! :P Guess I have to go learn the binary WebSocket protocol now...

The actual JSON command I am sending over the wire is `{"id":1,"method":"Page.reload"}`, as per [this python reloader](https://github.com/yohcop/devloop/blob/master/chrome-remote-reload.py) (where I got the idea from) and confirmed to be the correct command via [this Ruby-based remote control library](https://github.com/fgalassi/chrome-remote-debug/blob/master/lib/chrome_remote_debug/page.rb).

Any takers? :P

Comment: the header is only two bytes, and the second byte (ac and 1f) contains information about the size of the payload, so it is affected by the message being sent

Answer (score 1):

The library closes the connection right after it sends data, that's why you don't receive any answer. Don't call the function `curl_easy_cleanup` while you are working, cause it will close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for something which opens the socket, handles the underlying protocol and lets me handle just the data I need to send, kind of like "websocket netcat".

My new tool [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat) is explicitly advertised as "websocket netcat".

`nc -e` analogue is also supported: you can start your program and it will be connected to WebSocket with stdin/stdout.

Example using Chrome debugging port:

```
chromium --remote-debugging-port=9222&
ws=`curl -sg http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/new | grep webSocketDebuggerUrl | cut -d'"' -f4 | head -1`
echo '{"id":2,"method":"Page.navigate","params":{"url":"https://example.com"}}'  | websocat -n1 $ws
```